# LARAVEL 5.3 - Validator custom messages ignored

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I got in my login post method:

```
$validator = Validator::make(
    $request->all(), 
    [
        'user' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ],[
        'user' => 'Username is required',
        'password' => 'Password is required'
    ]
);
```

But unless I change `'password' => 'Password is required'` to `'password.required' => 'Password is required'`, the custom message is ignored and the default is sent to the view.

Do I really have to specify the rule in the message or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel looks first on custom messages and if it is not able to find one then it falls back to normal validation messages.

`'password' => 'Password is required'` is not for required validation your have set. so the default message is working. You have to write custom message on specific error type.

Example: password is required and should also be integer then

```
$validator = \Validator::make(
        $request->all(), 
        [
            'password' => 'required|integer'
        ],[
            'password.integer' => 'Password needs to be interger',
            'password.required' => 'Password is required'
        ]
);
```

Note: you can also set your custom messages in validation.php file and add   your messages in custom array. You will be able to use your custom messages globally then.

```
'custom' => [
    'attribute-name' => [
        'rule-name' => 'custom-message',
    ],
]
```

Comment: Custom messages should go before default ones doesnt matter if its generic or not but I guess itll have to do

Answer (score 0):

> Do I really have to specify the rule in the message or am I doing
>   something wrong?

The 'required' rule already have a default message. You can simply leave it out.  So this will work:

```
$validator = Validator::make(
    $request->all(), 
    [
        'user' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]
);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#working-with-error-messages

Comment: I do not want to use the default message

Answer (score 0):

My idea is creating in lang folder for specific language like EN, ES new file for request and using this into Requests model created for specified form.